# How do I upload a .tar file that contains a Google Cloud Shell workspace into another IDE?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, directory, tar, google-cloud-shell

I have an issue with Google Cloud Shell where it deletes my stuff so I backed up my whole workspace, directory really of all my coding files, and it got downloaded as a .tar file but I don't know how to work with the .tar file to access my workspace of files again. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you describe more precisely on which environment you are? What is the relation with Cloud Shell? And what you want to achieve?

Comment: It looks like you have compressed your files, you just need to [untar](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/how-to-open-a-tar-file-in-unix-or-linux/) it.

Comment: Please check if you are using [Cloud Shell Ephemeral Mode](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/using-cloud-shell#choosing_ephemeral_mode).

Comment: @guillaume I am using Google Cloud Shell, an in browser environment with a command line. I used it for some time instead of a different one like VSCode so I downloaded the Cloud shell workspace aka directory and it downloaded as a TAR file. I want to upload the workspace again so it opens up all the folders in my directory but it just sticks as a TAR file. sorry I don’t know how to reply directly

Comment: If I rephrase, you have got a cloud shell backup in TAR file and you wand to restore it in a new cloud shell. Is it correct? If so, I understand that you have untar your file in the new CLoud Shell and you have the list of directories but not restored as before. Still correct?